# i18next.t returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have this `.js` file that holds all my app's routes:

```js
import i18n from "i18next";

const dashRoutes = [
  // ...
  {
    path: "/user-profile",
    navbarName: i18n.t("userProfile"),
    component: UserProfile,
    layout: "/admin"
  },
// ...


export default dashRoutes;
```

And it is imported into `index.js` like so:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./i18n";
import routes from "routes.js";

class App extends React.Component {

getRoutes = routes => {
    return routes.map((r, index) => {
        return (
          <PrivateRoute
            navbarName={r.navbarName} // here it is always undefined
          />
        );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return this.getRoutes(routes);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

For some reason, `r.navbarName` is always `undefined` for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: is the script missing an export or did you omit that?

Comment: It does have an export. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are exporting `dashRoutes` you must import `dashRoutes` itself and not `routes`. if you want the variable to be named `routes` then do one of the following:

`import dashRoutes as routes from "routes.js";`

`import * as routes from "routes.js";`

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) default exports can be imported with their exact names only, if you want to import it with a different name then you can do it as above

Comment: It works. Thanks. I actually changed `routes.js` to `export default [...]`.

Comment: In two minutes I will.